# android development - can't with starting new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new in Android programming and I need to start a new `Activity` but everything I have done till now doesn't work.

This is what I have now:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private EditText  username=null;
    private EditText  password=null;
    private Button sendLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.gebruikersnaam);
        EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wachtwoord);
        sendLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

        public void sendLogin (View view) {
        if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && 
        password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
            //correcct password
            Intent homepage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(homepage);}
        else{
            //wrong password
        }
```

Comment: `startActivity()` and `MainActivity.this.startActivity()` is the same method being called.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.gebruikersnaam);
EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wachtwoord);
```

to

```
username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.gebruikersnaam);
password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wachtwoord);
```

You have re-declared your variables and initialized them in `onCreate` where as the instance variables are not initialized and your app crashes

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not called sendlogin method please try this

```
         sendLogin.setonclicklistner(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               sendLogin();

        }
    };)
```

Comment: op has `andorid:onClcick= "sendLoging"` in xml